# Find equation of the Tangent Plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$z=f(x,y)$ at point $P$

$f(x,y)= \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$, $P=(3,4,5)$.

I took the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$. For the partial with respect to $x$ I got $x(x^2 + y^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. For the partial with respect to y I got $y(x^2 + y^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

so the tangent is:

$\frac{9}{5}(3)(x-3)+\frac{16}{5}(4)-z+5=0$

Answer (score 1):

equation of Tangent plane at surface $z=f(x,y)$ at its point $P(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is

$$z=f(x_0,y_0)+f'_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f'_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$$

Partial derivatives are $$f'_x=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},f'_y=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Thus the plane has equation
$$z=5+\frac{3}{5}(x-3)+\frac{4}{5}(y-4)$$
which simplified becomes $3 x+4 y-5 z=0$